# Prism 5 - MVVM Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

With the release of the **Prism 5** on 04/18/2014, i see a new library named **Prism.MVVM.**

Prior versions of **PRISM** was not a **MVVM Framework**... we can now say that it can be compared to **MVVMLight** for example, its a real MVVM framework(or a complete)?

Whats the benefits to use MVVMLight with the Prism5? its really necessary right now?

Prism 5 MSDN Link: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx)

Prism 5 Prism.MVVM Class Library Link: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

> The **Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm** portable class library contains **ViewModelLocationProvider**, **BindableBase**, **ErrorsContainer**, **PropertySupport**, **CompositeCommand**, **DelegateCommand**, **DelegateCommandBase**, and **WeakEventHandlerManager**.
>
> The **Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.Desktop** assembly contains the WPF **ViewModelLocator** attach property.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: We know that prior versions of Prism was not a MVVM Framework... not we can consider it is? i will redo my question. sory for misunderstood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous versions of **Prism 4.2** and **Prism 4.1** updated to **.Net4.5** also have the ***MVVM*** project library. Based on my understanding, the reason for this change in the structure implementation was to have the ability for using *Nuget* packages.

For clarification, there is no need to use ***MVVM*** when using **Prism** and you may keep working as before from that point of view. The following ***Quickstarts*** are examples of this behavior:

- **HelloWorld**
- **EventAggregator**
- **Modularity**
- **Interactivity** (*CustomPopupView.xaml* class)

However, although it is not necessary, ***MVVM*** pattern is reccomended to be used on scenarios where it would be logical to apply it.

I hope I answered your question, Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Like GOstrowsky saying earlier versions of prism does have MVVM related support but Prism is not just for MVVM applications. Since Prism 5 is only for WPF desktop apps and WPF goes well with MVVM pattern prism also supports some basic MVVM related artifacts.
1. DelegateCommand
2. EventToCommand 
3. ViewmodelBase
and more....

MVVM Light vs Prism
like I said prism is not mvvm base framework its major focus is on to Composite applications development.

MVVM light is light weight framework of prism where its focus is mainly on mvvm based applications but to take advantage of dependency injection, messaging and event to command this is a simple framework that works for Silverlight/wpf/windows phone. MVVM light is not suitable for composite application development

key components of mvvmlight:
eventtocommand
relaycommand
messenger
IServicelocator
IViewmodelLocator

but all the above are now also available in prism 5.
I hope I answered your question